# display a real in verilog but bitstoreal returning only 0.000000

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am trying to display a real number during the simulation of my verilog code in modelsim. But I only get 0 as output. I am trying to use the bitstoreal system function. I'm not so good at verilog so it could be a stupid beginner's mistake.

Following is my code:

```
reg [31:0] y[1:0];
integer    file;
localparam [31:0] test = 32'h3fb0d05d;

task read_data_from_fifo();
   begin
     file = $fopen("/tmp/data.fifo", "r");
     $fread(y, file);
     $display("y0 = %d, %f, %h", $bitstoreal(y[0]), $bitstoreal(test), $bitstoreal(y[0]));
     $display("y1 = %f, %f, %h", y[1], $bitstoreal(32'h5dd0_b03f), y[1]);    
   end
endtask
```

(the task is called from an initial begin block)
Outputs:

```
# y0 =          0, 0.000000, 00000000
# y1 = 3742779199.000000, 0.000000, df16473f
```

All help appreciated.

### Update

Looks like bitstoreal only supports double precision floats (64-bit). Because

```
localparam [63:0] test = 64'h_3FF61A0BE5109071;
$display("%f", $bitstoreal(test));
```

results in

```
1.381359
```

Comment: Why? I think the problem is bitstoreal only support 64 bit floats!

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't guess you wanted it because as the values are read in as can be seen in the output of y[1]. Also the display of localparam is not dependant on any file. Anyhow, the file is a fifo, and it gets binary data written to it like `fwrite(y, 4, 2, file);` where y is a `const float *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use $bitstoshortreal:
...
$shortrealtobits converts values from a shortreal type to the 32-bit vector representation of the real
number.
$bitstoshortreal converts a bit pattern created by $shortrealtobits to a value of the shortreal
type.
...

Comment: This is the best answer. No need for complicated conversions.

Answer (score 3):

$bitstoreal takes a 64bit input double precision float.

Solution: Do a bit conversion from single to double precision float. Like this:

```
reg [31:0] z;      // single precision float
reg [63:0] double; // double precision float

double = {z[31], z[30], {3{~z[30]}}, z[29:23], z[22:0], {29{1'b0}}};

$display("%f", $bitstoreal(double));
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this single to double conversion is safe/correct.

### Update

This is to be read in the IEEE document mentioned by toolic:

$realtobits converts values from a real type to a 64-bit vector representation of the real number.
$bitstoreal converts a bit pattern created by $realtobits to a value of the real type.